# Validating url's with react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router

I have an object which contains some parameters like this:

```
notesList: {
    "1": {title: "First note", text: "Here is the first note"},
    "2": {title: "Second note", text: "Here is the second note"},
  }
```

where keys are notes ID's and the value are note contents.

And also I have NavLinks which changes url to the note ID value:

```
<NavLink to={`/${props.id}`}>
  <div className={styles.note}>
    {props.title}
  </div>
</NavLink>
```

Is there any way to validate these urls and do a redirect everytime (for example to the root derictory) when the url is changed manually to a value that is not in the IDs list (notesList keys)?